# Update CListCtrl after loading Variable with serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc, clistctrl

So I saved a Variaable with Serialize in MFC

```
void CDatenbankDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << Eintrag[0].name;
    }
    else
    {
        ar >> Eintrag[0].name;
    }
}
```

Whenever I loaded the variable, I have to call a function in my CMyView class.

```
void CDatenbankView::InsertAfterOpen()
{
    //DOC
    CDatenbankDoc* pDoc = CDatenbankDoc::GetDoc ();
    ASSERT_VALID (pDoc);

    i = m_List.InsertItem (i, pDoc->Eintrag[i].name);
}
```

Its to update my CListCtrl.
The problem is, I cant call the function in my Serialize function with `pView->InsertAfterOpen();`. Whenever I do this, the Variable has no Value. I dont really know why.
Does anyone know, how to update the CListCtrl after I loaded the Variable?

Answer (score 0):

In the MFC doc/view architecture you call UpdateAllViews when the document has changed data. This causes OnUpdate to be called in each view associated with the document. So put code in your view OnUpdate. You can update everything there, or use the lHint parameter to update a specific thing.